# Javascript Data Structures for Efficient Insertion and Searching

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures

I am in need of a Javascript data structure which will allow me to insert strings and search for strings efficiently. I have been looking around and the only data structures I have come across are objects and arrays. Objects are more used for encapsulation and cannot really be used for searching and using arrays can be slow. Are there any other data structures that will allow me to insert and search strings efficiently? Right now at best I could do a binary search on an array. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate on what sort of "searches" you wish to perform.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by "insert" and "search"?

Comment: Well I would like to insert a string into some data structure and later go back and search that data structure to see if that string is present or not. The number of strings searched is rather large and occurs frequently thus using a linear search (for loop) is not the best way to go.

Comment: Search for an exact match, or partial?

Comment: The chances are a List/"Array" (scan) or Map/"Object" (direct lookup or scan) will fulfill your requirements; `O(n)` for a small n is mostly meaningless. However, there are many ADTs that can be implemented in JavaScript, should there *be a need*. As such, I am voting to close this question -- **not enough details**.

Comment: @ewein So then use a Map/"Object". `strs = {"hello world": 1}; "hello world" in strs // -> true in "O(1)" time` (Remember that keys used in accessing object properties are automatically converted to strings, which is *okay here* because they are only strings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Objects are more used for encapsulation and cannot really be used for
>   searching

That was true in classical languages, not so true in JS.

```
   var obj = { memberone: "value1" }

   var value = obj["memberone"];

   //value === "value1"
```

Objects can be searched in JS. Bear with me...

> and using arrays can be slow.

Yes, can be - but don't have to be.

> Are there any other data structures that will allow me to insert and
>   search strings efficiently?

Data structures? No. Again that is a classical perspective. In JS, it is different.

Check out [_underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

1. It is 4k min gzip.
2. It provides a number of advanced iterator helpers (so you don't have to)
3. It provides templates to display your data to screen efficently.
4. It will benefit the rest of your development, maintenance, and implementations.

This is a good example of JS flexibility.

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Nash

Answer (score 1):

There are some more I found after some goggling,

[Javascript data structures - a collection object](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4138-javascript-data-structures-the-string-object.html)

One more thing you can use json objects and its JavaScript API to manipulate same. Please refer same [here](http://www.json.org/)